# Finder displays wrong volume names, drive status (High Sierra)

Tags: finder, disk-utility, high-sierra, external-disk

[image: wrong volume names]

My JetDrive volume is inexplicably showing as "Dropbox Installer" in the Finder. If I eject and re-mount it, the same.

Also "TB Backup" is supposedly mounted, according to Disk Utility, but Finder does not show an eject button.

If I try to browse "TB Backup" I get:

[image: TB Backup can't be opened]

This mess is preventing my SuperDuper backups from working.

Comment: ah well, rebooting fixed it

Answer (score 1):

I was able to go to the apple menu, choose 'force quit' and choose finder.  The button changed to relaunch and then it picked up my volumes correctly.

This still seems like a bug, but this will fix it without rebooting. :)